# Build cursor query dynamic in nature?

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I have below cursor which i am using in **PL/SQL function i.e getEmployeeInfo**

```
CURSOR employeeDepartment IS
        SELECT *
        FROM Employee
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Department ON Department.empID = Employee.ID
        WHERE Employee.STATE = 'Washington'
        ORDER BY Employee.JoiningDate desc;
```

I need to **modify getEmployeeInfo** function to take **employeeId as input parameter** and  append to **cursor employeeDepartment**
if `employeeId>0`.

I am new to PL/SQL programming. Looks like i need to move in direction of **REF-CURSOR** but i am not able make it up exactly?

So cursor query should be below if **Employee.id > 0** otherwise it should be same as above

```
CURSOR employeeDepartment IS
        SELECT *
        FROM Employee
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Department ON Department.empID = Employee.ID
        WHERE Employee.STATE = 'Washington'
        and Employee.id= 100
        ORDER BY Employee.JoiningDate desc;
```

**UPDATE :-** @APC solution worked. By Going with that solution if i user want to pass array of empId's instead of single Id i tried below

First created the array type with `create type p_employee_arr as table of number`

```
CURSOR employeeDepartment  (p_employee_arr IN num_array) IS
    SELECT *
    FROM Employee
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Department ON Department.empID = Employee.ID
    WHERE Employee.STATE = 'Washington'
    and (Employee.id in  (SELECT column_value  FROM TABLE( p_employee_arr )) or p_employee_arr is null)
    ORDER BY Employee.JoiningDate desc;
```

But still it return complete resultset if i provide one element in array

Comment: Your data model seems a bit odd - normally employees are assigned to a Department, rather than the other way around.

Comment: i just quote an example to draw the analogy from problem i am facing.Yes may be its not right. But thats not a concern here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit ambiguous but I think you want to restrict the result set when an Employee ID is passed, otherwise you want all the records for the state .

```
CURSOR employeeDepartment  (p_employee_id in number) IS
    SELECT *
    FROM Employee
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Department ON Department.empID = Employee.ID
    WHERE Employee.STATE = 'Washington'
    and ( p_employee_id = 0 or Employee.id= p_employee_id )
    ORDER BY Employee.JoiningDate desc;
```

Comment: Exactly i am looking for this only. Thanks

Comment: One more small modification i want is is user is passing array of empId's instead of single empId, then i want those
those specific information otherwise get all. Should it be ...(p_arr_employee_id is null or Employee.id in (p_arr_employee_id))

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the cursor with parameter like below

```
CURSOR employeeDepartment (employee_id_in IN number)
IS
        SELECT *
        FROM Employee
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Department ON Department.empID = Employee.ID
        WHERE Employee.STATE = 'Washington'
        and 
        (case 
               when (employee_id_in > 0) and (Employee.id= employee_id_in)  then 1
        else 0
        end) = 1 
        ORDER BY Employee.JoiningDate desc;
```

hence you can open the cursor like

```
open employeeDepartment(100)
```

for more information refer http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/declare.php

Comment: I want to append and clause " and Employee.id=.." only when empId >0. With your solution it will always append that condition

Comment: use `case` statements in `where` clause.

Comment: can you provide example here